# How can I solve the following equation for the vector $r$?

Tags: matrix-equations, linear-regression

I am currently trying to compute the maximal possible correlation between a predictor and a latent variable in a structural equation model given the amount of predictors, the collinearity between them and the multiple determination coefficient $R^2$. If necessary, all predictor effect sizes could be constraint to be equivalent. I found that the formula for $R^2$ is as follows
$$R^2 = c^TR^{-1}_{xx}c,$$

with $R^{-1}_{xx}$ being the inverse of the correlation matrix among the predictors and $c$ being the vector of the correlation between the predictors and the outcome variable. Is there a way to solve for $c$?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring all the setup, it appears that you're asking whether given an $n \times n$ square matrix (which you've called $R_{xx}^{-1}$, but I'll call $M$, and a nonnegative number $H$ (which you've called $R^2$), can we solve for $c$ in
$$
H = c^t M c.
$$

The answer is evidently no, for if $M$ is the identity, and $H = 1$, then $c$ can be any point on the unit sphere.

Even if that were not the case, the function
$$
f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R: c \mapsto c^t M c
$$
takes $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$ smoothly. Unless $M$ is the zero matrix, you'd expect this to be a submersion at almost every point of $\Bbb R$, so that the preimage of a point would be an $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold. In particular, you'd expect
$$
f^{-1}(R^2)
$$
to be an $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold, hence consist of more than one point.

Comment: Thank your for your answer! Your generalization boils it down to the core of my question, even though i thought giving a bit of background for my desired application might be helpful. If i understood your explanation correctly, there is no solution for **c** since it consists of more than one distinct value. If one were to constrain all elements of the vector to be equal (say **v**), would it in turn then be possible to compute this value (**v**)?

Comment: Sure...you could do that. Let $u = \pmatrix{1\\1\\ \vdots \\1}$, and let $h = f(u)/H$. Then $c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{h}} u$ would be **a** solution of your problem. Unless there's some obvious preference for your chosen coordinate system, however, a solution like that is almost certain to be meaningless in the context of your problem. So while you **can** find such a solution, I'm suggesting that you may not really **want** to.